# Using domready for AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there a way to know that the elements are on a document before I try to access them with JQuery?

#### Code Snippet:

```
var s = new AjaxCall(someurl);

s.oncomplete = function(response) {
    var container = $('container_id');
    container.innerHTML = response;
    var ul = $('some_id'); }
```

The response is some HTML returned by the Ajax call.

This response updates the contents of a `div` and then I access an element that was created by the `innerHTML` (the `ul` in the code).

If the response is large, I believe there would be times that some elements would not be rendered when I will try to access them. Does `domready` work for AJAX calls, and could this solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten to use `#`, as it should be `$('#some_id');`, and not  `$('some_id');`. I suggest instead to just use `document.getElmenetById`. It reads more clearly and is much more efficient than contextual-based ID matching.

```
var some_id = document.getElmenetById("some_id");
```

Regarding your question of the element "not being available," don't worry. The innerHTML setter performs a synchronous operation. If a tag with a matching ID is parsed from that, then the corresponding element will be available immediately after setting the innerHTML.

Comment: Hi Garrett,

Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

If you were using jQuery, your `success` function for the request would be:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(resp){
    var ul = $("#containerID").html(resp).find("#ElementInRespID");
    //do something with ul
  }
});
```

This will put the result in the container, find the element you want in there and set the `ul` variable to it.

Comment: Hi there,

I am not using JQuery though. Does anyone know what JQuery uses in order to achieve the above code?

I am pretty sure they are calling innerHTML also, in their html method.

Comment: @Thomas - They're calling well, a lot of stuff :)  The beatuy is it takes out the cross-browser headaches.  The full source is available for browsing though, here's the ajax portion so you can see what's going on: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js